# Attempting a double Gaussian for the data below

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian, scipy-optimize

Blue curve is raw data, green curve is the Gaussian fit for only the second maximum and yellow curve is the combination of Gaussian for both maxima. Context: `yraw` is raw data in a list, `xpixel` is the x axis (500-1250)

Here is my Gaussian method:

```
def Gauss(x, amp, mu, sigma): 
    return amp*np.exp(-((x-mu)/(np.sqrt(2)*sigma))**2)

def bimode(x, amp1, mu1, sigma1, amp2, mu2, sigma2):
    return Gauss(x, amp1, mu1, sigma1) + Gauss(x, amp2, mu2, sigma2)


ypg1 = np.asarray(yraw) #make np array from raw data list



parameters, covarience = curve_fit(bimode, xpixel, ypg1, p0 = (78, 805, 15, 8, 950, 15)) #does a curve fit for our gauss function. we give it an initial guess of amplitude, mean value (95,000)
#parameters returns amp, mu, sig, amp, mu, sig
print(parameters)


ygauss = bimode(xpixel, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3], parameters[4], parameters[5])
```

I am expecting a nice curve fit from double Gaussian to envelope both maxima.
[image]

Comment: It's a bit difficult to continue if we don't have the data, but my guess is that your model is just doing what it's supposed to do. Minimize the total residual. If it was to hyper focus on your second gaussian, it would increase the total residual of the remainder of the curve. You *could* try fitting a third gaussian, or try some baseline removal technique (I think rubberband might work), or you could separate the two gaussians and fit them separately, but you should limit the second one to your region either by sectioning your array (don't forget to rescale) or using weights.

Comment: Could you post your dataset, no screenshot, copy paste or provide a link

Answer (score 0):

Let's create some dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize, stats
from pybaselines import Baseline, utils

p0 = (78, 810, 20, 8, 940, 20)

np.random.seed(12345)

x = np.linspace(500, 1250, 300)
y = model(x, *p0)
n = stats.gamma.rvs(a=1, size=y.size)
baseline = peak(x, 10, 850, 100)
yn = y + n + baseline
```

Now remove the baseline:

```
fitter = Baseline(x)
background = fitter.noise_median(yn)[0]

ynb = yn - background
```

And fit:

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(
    model, x, ynb, p0=(100, 800, 10, 10, 950, 10)
)
```

Both peak can be found:

[image]